# How could I avoid using the name of an object property along with the this keyword in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, object, properties, this, object-literal

How could I avoid using the name of an object property along with the this keyword in TypeScript?

E.g. I can write:

```
const foo = 2;
const bar = 3;
const baz = { foo, bar };
```

But I can not do the following:

```
class A {
    foo: number = 2;
    bar: number = 3;
    f() {
        const baz = { this.foo, this.bar };
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you could first do `const { foo, bar } = this;`, but why not just `const baz = { foo: this.foo, bar: this.bar }`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I just want to use a more succinct version. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really averse to any repetition at all you can write yourself a helper method:

```
class A {
    foo: number = 2;
    bar: number = 3;
    f() {
        const baz = select(this, "foo", "bar")
    }
}

function select<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...props: Array<K>): Pick<T, K> {
    const copy = {} as Pick<T, K>;
    props.forEach(p => copy[p] = obj[p])
    return copy
}
```